# Num vs Integral

Tags: haskell

This function:

```
hola :: (Integral a) => a -> String
hola 1 = "OK"
hola _ = "asdf"
```

works fine. But this one:

```
hola :: (Num a) => a -> String
hola 1 = "OK"
hola _ = "asdf"
```

can't be compiled: "Could not deduce (Eq a) arising from the literal `1'"

I really don't get it. I am reading a tutorial where it is said

> "Integral is also a numeric typeclass. Num includes all numbers, including real numbers and integral numbers, Integral includes only integral (whole) numbers. In this typeclass are Int and Integer." http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses

Why can't I use Num?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's a recent change [proposed and accepted in September/October last year](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2011-September/016699.html), in the latest version of the base package, `Eq` and `Show` are no longer superclasses of `Num`. Since that change, no new version of the language report has been published, so it's not yet in the report. And since it's recent, it has also not made it yet into many tutorials or books.

"Pattern matching" against a numeric literal is an implicit application of `(==)`, so an `Eq` instance is required for it to work. That instance can now no longer be inferred from the `Num` constraint, so the (quite new :D) compiler rejects the code with only a `Num` constraint.

But `Integral` is a subclass of `Real`, which has `Ord` (and hence `Eq`) as a superclass, hence that works.

Comment: Working in the previuous version :) Thank you!! I think this change make this language a bit confusing.. :(

Comment: Well, it will certainly cause a lot of confusion (and breakage of packages) in the transition period. But the overall consensus was that the gain is greater than the loss (no more spurious `Eq` and `Show` instances for things like functions that can have sensible `Num` instances except for the old `Eq` and `Show` requirements). The same (mutatis mutandis) applies to the removal of the `Num` superclass from `Bits`. Fortunately, the breakages are _backward-compatibly_ fixed by adding the constraints.

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel, your answers were very useful. So with the new compiler I have to ensure that the constraint includes a Eq instance at least in order to make the comparison.

Comment: Yes, since `Eq` and `Show` are no longer implied by `Num`, with the new compiler, you have to explicitly (for values of "explicitly" that include "implicitly through other constraints") add them where you use them.

Answer (score 9):

As Daniel Fischer said, it used to work but it now doesn't work because `Num` and `Eq` were split so `Num a` does not imply `Eq a` anymore. To fix your code just make `Eq a` explicit:

```
hola :: (Num a, Eq a) => a -> String
hola 1 = "OK"
hola _ = "asdf"
```